# How to calculate the probability of winning Kakegurui rock paper scissors

Tags: probability, card-games

In the anime [Kakegurui](https://www.msn.com/en-us/entertainment/rf-watch-online/tv-shows/kakegurui/season-1), there is a variant of rock paper scissors played where the rules are:

- Initially, each player draws 3 cards from a random set of 20 cards, each card being either rock, paper or scissors
- The maximum number of rounds per game is 3
- On each round, each player picks a card and puts it down at the same time, the winner of the round wins, otherwise the game continues to the next round

How would one go about calculating the probabilities for the card game?

If an additional rule is included, so that when there is a winner on the very first hand (when each player has three cards), the loser can opt to replay that round (each player gets their card back and the round is started again). This can only be done once for each player. Again, how would such a rule affect the probabilities for the game?

Comment: What is the distribution of the cards in the initial set of $20$?

Comment: The key probability is that there is no result after all three pairs of cards are used; it depends on how the $20$ cards are chosen, but could be $\frac1{27}$.  This increases very slightly with the additional rule.

Comment: the initial distribution is random.

Comment: Do you mean that the cards are randomly sampled from a large population with equal proportions of each type, so that the deck contains, in expectation, $6\frac23$ cards of each type, in random order?

Comment: yes, exactly. However, in the anime, one player tries to rig the system by stacking the deck with one type of card.